# Bootstrap 4 - Active link CSS when in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble with styling the navbar when the screen is in mobile view.

The nav links are working as intended in the expanded view however on the mobile view i want to apply a different style.

Here is my code (.css)

```css
#mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link.active{
   border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: #f2e7b9;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767 px){
 #mainNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > .nav-item > .nav-link.active{
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: red;
 } 
}
```

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
       <div class="container">
         <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Logo</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
       </div>
    </nav>
```

It's mostly my css that i think is wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: what's not working about your current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra space in your media query after "767".

Yours:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767 px)
```

It should be:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will now double check everything including spaces.

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help. It happens to everyone.